# Multiple raw_inputs

Tags: python

```
#Print out the menu
print """
###############################################
# 1 - Introduction.                           #
# 2 - Base.                                   #
# 3 - Contact.                                #
###############################################"""

#Get the user's choice
choice = raw_input("")

#Work with choice
print choice
if choice == 1:
    print "# Welcome to xbrEra's first application!      #"
elif choice == 2:
    print "# This application was built in Python 7.2.1.  #"
elif choice == 3:
    print "# Contact me at Blackriver.era@hotmail.com     #"
else:
    print "# Invalid choice!                              #"
```

That is my code. My problem is that after the first input has been completed, they next inputs will have ">>> " as a prefix. How do I change this, and also I keep getting "Invalid choice!" in the current code. Please help, thank you!

Comment: empty string '""' is not necessary -- `raw_input()` can be called without arguments [with the same effect].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I keep getting "Invalid choice!" in the current code

`raw_input()` returns string in python 2.7, so you need to compare as

```
choice == "1"
```

<s>or you may try with `input()` instead of `raw_input()`, which evaluate input as numbers.</s>

or you could parse to integer with `int(raw_input())` as J.F. Sebastian pointed out. non-integer input could cause errors, so wrap it with try: except: block like

```
try:
  choice = int(raw_input(), 10)
except ValueError:
  choice = None
```

ps: ", 10" is for base 10, input could be zero padded like 010, which could take input as octal numbers

Comment: `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`; it should not be used for user input. `try: choice = int(raw_input()) except ValueError: print 'invalid choice'` could be used here.

Comment: bare `except` is not a good idea; it catches `KeyboardInterrupt` for example. `except ValueError` could be used here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Print out the menu

ch = """###############################################
# 1 - Introduction.                           #
# 2 - Base.                                   #
# 3 - Contact.                                #
###############################################

  Enter your choice : """

choice = raw_input(ch)
warn = "\n  You must enter 1 or 2 or 3.\n"+\
     "  Enter your choice : "
while choice not in ('1','2','3'):
    choice = raw_input(warn)

print ("# Welcome to xbrEra's first application!      #",
       "# This application was built in Python 7.2.1.  #",
       "# Contact me at Blackriver.era@hotmail.com     #")[int(choice)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to code your new lines like this '\n''You must enter 1, 2, or 3.''\n'