# Number Guesser Program Malfunction

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning Python: If condition executing all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739453/learning-python-if-condition-executing-all-the-time)

This Python code is for guessing a number from 1 to 100. There is nothing wrong with the 'guesser()' function, which I know because my program also has a "manual mode" that works perfectly. For some reason, it always assigns the 'guesss' value to 'low' and keeps doing so until it equals 100 and the program "Ragequits". It never does anything to 'high', which stays at its default throughout the execution. No matter what, it never executes the "winning" block.
NOTE: The variables 'high' and 'low' start as 101 and 0 respectively, and 'guesser()' chooses a number between them. 'goOn' is used earlier in the code to determine if the person wants to play again.

```
            num = raw_input('Enter the number which you want the computer to guess. ')
            unguessed = True
            while unguessed:
                if high == low + 1 or high <= low:
                    print 'Waitafligginflagginminnit! You CHEATED! *Ragequits*'
                    goOn = False
                    unguessed = False
                    print ''
                    raw_input('Press Enter to continue.')
                guesses = guesses + 1
                guesss = guesser()
                print 'I guessed', guesss
                if guesss == num:
                    print 'Yay! I won in', guesses, 'guesses!'
                    again = raw_input('Just press enter if you want to play again. Otherwise...you know the drill. ')
                    unguessed = False
                    print '\n\n'
                    if again:
                        goOn = False
                else:
                    print 'Awww...'
                    if guesss > num:
                        high = guesss
                    elif guesss < num:
                        low = guesss
```

Comment: no number between 1 and 100 will ever equal the string you're getting from the user; convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `int(raw_input())` instead of `raw_input` in order to retain the guess as an integer. `raw_input()` alone returns a string, and so comparisons will not hold.

See these previously answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077450/multiple-raw-inputs), and this exact [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739453/learning-python-if-condition-executing-all-the-time) as yours.

Comment: ...MAN! I hate that. Despite running a perfectly logically sound program, I trip over syntax and technicalities. Granter, they're _necessary_ syntax and technicalities, but still...sigh. At least it's better than it was in C#. Thanks, Raed.

Comment: Arguably, the problem would have been more obvious in C# in this case because you would have had a compile time error trying to assign a string to an int variable.